# Electron post-scss webpack parser error on build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, electron, electron-react-boilerplate

This is a boilerplate from electron-react. I've tried to include scss mixins but it seems to spit out with the following error:

```
CssSyntaxError: C:\C:\app\scss\base\_theme.scss:30:17: Unknown word
You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser

  28 | @mixin themed() {
  29 |     @each $theme, $map in $themes {
> 30 |       .theme--#{$theme} & {
     |                 ^
  31 |         $theme-map: () !global;
  32 |         @each $key, $submap in $map {
```

I've included postscss-loader to the webpack but the error still persist

Comment: were you able to solve that problem?